# how to compute Möbius transformation's determinant

Tags: analysis

$SL(2, R)$ acts on $H^2$ by Möbius transformations
$$ g\cdot z=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, \quad
g=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c  & d  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\in SL(2,R), \quad  z\in H^2,$$
where  $H^2=\{z\in C \mid \operatorname{Im} (z)>0\}$, i.e., the complex upper half plane.

My question is how to view the Jacobian of $M_g $ as a linear transformation on $R^2$, and  how to compute its determinant.  Here, $M_g$ denote the associated Möbius transformations.

The answer is $|cz+d|^{-4}$, but I cannot get that. please help me , thanks in advance.

Comment: The Jacobian of a holomorphic function is $\lvert f'(z)\rvert^2$. The derivative of the Möbius transformation is $$\frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer The OP has already normalized out the determinant, so your numerator is $1.$

Comment: That step was intentionally left out, @IgorRivin. Replacing it with $1$ in the normalised case should not be a problem, but as written, it's also correct in the non-normalised case.

Answer (score 1):

[Answered by Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613639/how-to-compute-mobius-transformations-determinant#comment1292287_613639):

> The Jacobian of a holomorphic function is $\lvert f'(z)\rvert^2$. The derivative of the Möbius transformation is $$\frac{ad-bc}{(cz+d)^2}.$$

With the $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ normalization, the numerator is $1$. Thus, the Jacobian is $|cz+d|^{-4}$.

Something like this is true in higher dimensions (in $\mathbb R^n$) too. Namely, the Jacobian of the inversion $x\mapsto x/|x|^2$ is $1/|x|^{2n}$. A general fractional linear transformation is the composition of linear map with inversion, followed by another linear map.